# ubuntu package version management

Tags: apt, package-management

Basically, I don't know what's the best practice to upgrade a package whose `apt` version is not update-to-date enough. Say I manually compile and install a package A with version x, and historically package A with version y (presumably y < x) is still installed. Should I delete A-y first? I'm wondering if there are tools that can do conflicts check (either automatically or manually) on ubuntu? Because I'm not always aware of the fact that an older version of A is installed.

Comment: Do you need a package (for distribution reasons) or is just compiling and installing into `/usr/local` (or `/opt`) an option?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I don't need a package for distribution. Just for the ease of maintenance. I think installing to `/usr/local` or `opt` would work but I need to update lld path then.